# Misplaced figure

Tags: floats, positioning

I don't understand why the figure is above the section title.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\clearpage
\section*{Códigos}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{fig/scilabKbarra}
\caption{Código \textit{Scilab} para cálculo de $\overline{K}$ e $K_t$}
\label{scilabKbarra}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a figure is a floating environment which by default can go to top of page, if you never want it to float backwards use `\usepackage{flafter}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should I use both packages at the same time?

Comment: there's some relevant information in the answer to this question: [Flafter sometimes ignores a section title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220949/579)

Comment: the packages  are not related `graphicx` defines commands for including graphics and rotation etc, such as `\includegraphics`  whereas `flafter`  (which is also part of the core latex release) modifies the float placement algorithm as used by `figure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually helps if you add `[h]` as option for place holder:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{article}    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
\section*{Códigos}

    \begin{figure}[h]% <--- it say "let figure be here"
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}
    \caption{Código \textit{Scilab} para cálculo de $\overline{K}$ e $K_t$}
\label{scilabKbarra}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]